# cvDecodeImage fail in a cgi program

Tags: opencv, cgi

In a single application, the following code is ok

```
CvMat src_image_mat;
cvInitMatHeader(&src_image_mat,1,src_image_data.size(), \
                CV_8U,(void *)src_image_data.c_str());
m_pSrcImage = cvDecodeImage(&src_image_mat, 0);
```

where src_image_data contains all the bytes in a given jpeg file, 
after calling ,m_pSrcImage is not NULL.

but when this code is run in a cgi program, the value cvDecodeImage returns is NULL, and the src_image_data is the same as in the single application.

btw: when in cgi context, the picture is uploaded by some users.

Answer (score 0):

assure file is already read into memory to pData with size nSize.

```
    CvMat cm = cvMat(1, nSize, CV_8UC1, pData);
    pImage = cvDecodeImage(&cm);
```